# Why is neuronal firing rate proportional to axonal diameter?

Tags: neuron

I know that a larger axonal diameter results in faster speed of action potentials due to reduced resistance. However this doesn't explain why the firing rate of neurons is proportional to neuronal diameter. Is it because higher spike rates require larger capacitance (since each spike charges the neuron) meaning a larger surface area and diameter of neuron is needed?

Comment: Can you quote a source for firing rate being proportional to diameter?

Comment: Principles of Neural Design (Simon and Laughlin), chapter 3 page 54. Also https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/19525561/ (Balasubramanian, Sterling 2009)

Comment: Also a short quote from each and edit into your question please (comments are meant to be temporary).